# JS Excluding Radio Button from window.onclick event listener

Tags: javascript, html

I have a document where there is a general event listener if the user clicks anywhere on the document, for this I used `window.onclick`. However, there a few instances where I want to specify that this event listener should not be triggered if the user clicks on certain things. In my case, if the user clicks on something with the class `circle` or with the class `radio-label`. The circle one worked fine:

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if(!(event.target.className.baseVal=='circle')) {
        ...
```

In addition to circles, I also would like this function not to trigger if the user clicks one of my radio buttons:

```
<form>
    <label class='radio-label'>Mode 1<input type='radio' value='Mode 1' id='rd1'></label>
</form>
```

I thought using the same approach by means of the `'radio-label'` class would work:

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if(!(event.target.className.baseVal=='circle')&&!(event.target.className.baseVal=='radio-label') {
        ...
```

But no luck. I wasn't sure what was going on for awhile, my radio button event listeners were not working. It wasn't until I commented out the whole `window.onclick` function, then I noticed things worked properly. So I have narrowed it down to that.

Also, my radio button is created at the beginning of the document, so I don't think it's an issue of asynchronous elements.

What needs to changed in my if statement?

Comment: @RolandStarke Should it be something else?

Comment: `event.target` in your case is the input element and it does not have a `className`. ... You should loop through all parents of your target and check if the class is somewhere there.

Comment: Turns out using: `event.target.id=='rd1'` is wayyyyy easier.